# postgresql online backup tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

Tags: postgresql, backup

everybody

I use  pg_start_backup and  pg_stop_backup to backup Postgresql Database.sometime backup log say  tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors; Then I find  backup log said tar: /data/pgsql/5432/base/21796/25283: file changed as we read it; How can I avoid this log ??

I test the backup is ok for  recovery ?

operational process is

1、 select pg_start_backup('labe');

2、 tar czvf data.tar.gz  /data/pgsql/5432 --exclude  /data/pgsql/5432/pg_xlog

3、 select pg_stop_backup();

second question is someone use pg_basebackup to backup postgresql ? I test is  the same as pg_start_backup and pg_stop_backup?

very thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does someone use pg_basebackup to backup your postgresql database ??

and pg_baebackup take  a full backup ervery day and use archive data to  recovery to point to time recovery

Answer (score 1):

*file changed as we read it* is just a warning and the backup is OK, provided `pg_start_backup` has been called. To silence the warning, if using GNU `tar`, you may add the option:

`--warning=no-file-changed`

See http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/warnings.html

[pg_basebackup](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgbasebackup.html) is another way of taking a hot backup. It differs mostly by not needing file access on the db server (it uses a PostgreSQL connection to get the data), and providing some specific options related to WAL files.